# How do I printout a 2 dimensional char array?

Tags: arrays, c

Im trying to make a tictactoe game in C and decided to use a 2d char array to create the gameboard.
A nested for loop is probably best suited for this but I cant quite understand how I should adress individual strings in an array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char board [5][8]={"  |  |  ","--+--+--","  |  |  ","--+--+--","  |  |  "};
    printf("%s",board[1][0]);




}
```

Comment: to print 1 character use %c instead of %s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your array is to short to keep the C string (which requires one element more to accommodate the null character) you cant use any C functions which operate on C strings.

How to print this array?:

```
int main(void) {
    char board [5][8]={"  |  |  ","--+--+--","  |  |  ","--+--+--","  |  |  "};
    for(size_t row = 0; row < sizeof(board) / sizeof(board[0]); row++)    
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < sizeof(board[0])/ sizeof(board[0][0]); col++)
            printf("%c", board[row][col]);  
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4qo4rx6oY

But if you change the size of the array you can use string functions.

```
int main(void) {
    char board [5][9]={"  |  |  ","--+--+--","  |  |  ","--+--+--","  |  |  "};
    for(size_t row = 0; row < sizeof(board) / sizeof(board[0]); row++)    
            printf("%s\n", board[row]);  
}
```